# How to apply validation on multiple partial views using the same model properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC..am developing a project of Employee Module there i need to save employee Education details (it includes SSLC,PUC,Graduation)so for that am using 3 partial views using same model..

Model is

```
public  class EmployeeEducationDetailTable
{
  public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
  public int EmployeeEducationDetailId { get; set; }
  [Required(ErrorMessage="Select qualification")]
  public int EmployeeQualificationTypeId { get; set; }
  [Required(ErrorMessage="Enter institute name")]
  public string EmployeeInstituteName { get; set; }
  [Required(ErrorMessage="Enter year of pass")]
  [DataType(DataType.Date)]
  [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
  public DateTime? EmployeeYearOfPass { get; set; }
  [Required(ErrorMessage="Enter percentage")]
  public string EmployeePercentage { get; set; }
  public List<EmployeeEducationDetailTable> employeeEducationList { get; set; }

  public EmployeeEducationDetailTable()
  {
    employeeEducationList = new List<EmployeeEducationDetailTable>();
  }

  public IEnumerable<EmployeeMainTable> employee_MainTable { get; set; }
  public ICollection<EmployeeQualificationTypeTable> employee_QualficationTypeTable { get; set; }
  // public IEnumerable<EmployeeQualificationTypeTable> employee_QualficationTypeTable { get; set; } 
}



 public  class EducationSectionDetails
    {

        public EmployeeEducationDetailTable SSLC { get; set; }
        public EmployeeEducationDetailTable PUC { get; set; }
    }
```

In My View

```
@model Employee.DAL.ModelClasses.EducationSectionDetails

@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateEmployeeEducationDetails","Employee",FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

     <h3>SSLC</h3>
  @Html.Partial("_Emp_Education",Model.SSLC,new ViewDataDictionary() 
  { 
    TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo() 
      { HtmlFieldPrefix = "SSLC" } })

  <h3>PUC</h3>
  @Html.Partial("_Emp_Education",Model.PUC,new ViewDataDictionary() 
    { TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo() 
      { HtmlFieldPrefix = "PUC" } })

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />


}
```

_Emp_Education Partial View

```
<table>   
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeQualificationTypeId,"Qualification")
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EmployeeQualificationTypeId,ViewBag.QualificationTypeId as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>,"--Select--")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeQualificationTypeId)
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeInstituteName,"University/Institute")
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmployeeInstituteName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeInstituteName)
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeYearOfPass,"Year Of Pass")
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmployeeYearOfPass)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeYearOfPass)
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeePercentage,"Percentage/Grade")
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmployeePercentage)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeePercentage)
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In Controller

```
 public ActionResult CreateEmployeeEducationDetails()
        {
            EducationSectionDetails e = new EducationSectionDetails();
            e.SSLC = new EmployeeEducationDetailTable();
            e.PUC = new EmployeeEducationDetailTable();
               return View(e);

        }




 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CreateEmployeeEducationDetails(EducationSectionDetails tbl)
        {
          //Code 
         }
```

it is Successfully posting the data of SSLC,PUC but problem is Validation need to perform on section wise with one Submit button.Sometimes sections are optional user may or may not enter the data of perticular section.In this case How to handle Validation?

Comment: Not getting validation is the least of your problems. This is creating duplicate id (invalid html) and name attributes so it wont post back and bind to your model

Comment: Hello Stephen Can you have look on code again..

Comment: You should be creating view models to represent what you want to display and edit. Your `EmployeeEducationDetailTable` model does make sense (why does it contain a list of `EmployeeEducationDetailTable`?) You have said you want 3 `Education` details, but you only render 2 partials (which is it?). You should also be using a custom `EditorTemplate` for the `EmployeeEducationDetailTable` view model (not a partial) and then `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.SSLC)`.

Comment: As for the validation issue, you either have it or not. You would need to have a duplicate view model for the optional details (without the validation attributes) or you would to use jquery to disable validation on the controls you want to ignore (but what would trigger that?)